# Linux Mint 13 is not booting on dual boot computer

Tags: linux, multi-boot, linux-mint

I have 2 hard drives in my computer a 300 GB drive which is my primary drive for windows 7 and a 1.5 TB drive that I'd used for storage. When I got it I partitioned 500 GB for use in Linux.

So, I created a bootable USB and clicked the "Install by Current Operating System" option from Mint. It installed it to the free 500 GB like I'd hoped it would. Now, I can't get it to boot though. I've tried using EasyBCD to create the boot entry and it hangs on a black screen.

---

@Ryhuk: It presents a menu with two options 1) Windows and 2) Mint. This was a menu I created with easyBCD. When I select option 1 it boots to windows fine. When I select option 2 it hangs on a black screen with just a white bar flashing (Can't remember what its called, it marks the current cursor location on a text field) and won't respond to any key presses but <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>.

Comment: Let me see if I understood correctly. You have Windows in HD (1) and Mint in HD (2). Now, when you turn on your computer it normally boots up directly into Windows 7 without any prompt or something?

Comment: (This comment was inserted alongside the question which was really a reply for @Rhyuk) It presents a menu with two options 1) Windows and 2) Mint. This was a menu I created with easyBCD. When I select option 1 it boots to windows fine. When I select option 2 it hangs on a black screen with just a white bar flashing (Can't remember what its called, it marks the current cursor location on a text field) and won't respond to any key presses but alt ctrl del.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't solved it, the installation seems to have done well.  This sounds like a graphic driver problem that is giving a black screen. While in boot menu, move to linux line and press 'e' which is edit. At the end of 4th line that starts with search --floppy, add these words `--nomodeset` and give boot option (i think its ctrl+x to boot from there). After this you should be able to pass the black screen and login. This image shows the line:

[image]

After booting in you can check your loaded graphics driver with this command lsmod | grep nou. It should probably be nouveau driver which won't work with many systems. Best would be to search for driver according to your graphics card from synaptic package manager under menus. It will suggest the right driver. Hope this helps.